# printing only contents of div - popup

Tags: javascript, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print contents of a modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465872/print-contents-of-a-modal-popup)

I am using the following solution to print the contents of the popup :

```
 function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    window.print();

    window.onfocus = function () { document.body.innerHTML = originalContents };
}
```

The content is actually displayed in a popup. The above solution works fine in all browsers except `IE8`. When I tried to print the content, by calling the above function - `IE8` prints the entire content of the page along with a  black box in next page?

How to fix this bug in `IE8`? Thanks for the help/suggestions.

Comment: how about a jquery plugin to fix the problem?

Comment: any suggestions on the plugin? Thanks !

Comment: check here http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-print-page-options/